# Append input to existing list

Tags: python

I'm running through a beginners guide to Python and I'm currently working on lists. Now I've created this sample code, but I can't seem to add the user input dynamically to the list that I've created. If you enter an item from the list, you get a success message, but if the item isn't on the list I try to append it to the current list and then I return an error message that it's not in the inventory. The last line is just printing out the list in hopes that the new addition is there. I've tried the append method and even tried extending into another list. Can someone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
topping_list_one = ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'peppers']
error_message = "Sorry we don't have "
success_message = "Great, we have "

first_topping = raw_input ('Please give me a topping: ')
if ( first_topping in topping_list_one ) :
    print '{}!'.format(success_message + first_topping) 
elif ( first_topping in topping_list_one ): 
    topping_list_one.append('first_topping')
else : 
    print '{}'.format(error_message + first_topping)
print 'Heres a list of the items now in our inventory: {}'.format(topping_list_one)
```

Comment: Your if and your elif have the same conditional. Only the first one will ever execute. Also, if it were to ever execute, it would add the literal 'first_topping' and not the value of the variable `first_toppping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two condition statements are exactly the same, and according to your description of your target, I think you need append user input under the else flow which is like following code.

```
topping_list_one = ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'peppers']
error_message = "Sorry we don't have "
success_message = "Great, we have "

first_topping = raw_input ('Please give me a topping: ')
if first_topping in topping_list_one:
    print '{}!'.format(success_message + first_topping)  
else: 
    print '{}'.format(error_message + first_topping)
    topping_list_one.append(first_topping)
print 'Heres a list of the items now in our inventory:{}'.format(topping_list_one)
```

BTW I point two problems of your code

1. You need write it in Python's way, forget `if()` in other languages, python don't need parentheses in condition statement (although add parentheses will not trigger syntax error).
2. Append variable `first_topping` and not string `first_topping`,I think it cased by carelessness :-)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that seems to have done the trick. I found some old python code online that included the ( ) , but I cleaned. Thank you much

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean to say

```
elif ( first_topping not in topping_list_one ): 
    topping_list_one.append(first_topping)
```

ie. "not in" instead of "in" and remove the quotes from 'first_topping'

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not very consistent and also have some errors. You should just have two `if` conditions there. If the topping is in the list, print it and if it is not, you either add the new or simply show an error message.

Of course you can have both if you make a condition to not add special characters and what not to the list.

Adding a new topping:

```
topping_list_one = ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'peppers']
error_message = "Sorry we don't have "
success_message = "Great, we have "

first_topping = raw_input ('Please give me a topping: ')
if first_topping in topping_list_one :
    print '{}!'.format(success_message + first_topping) 
else :
    topping_list_one.append(first_topping)
print 'Heres a list of the items now in our inventory: {}'.format(topping_list_one)
```

Error message:

```
topping_list_one = ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'peppers']
error_message = "Sorry we don't have "
success_message = "Great, we have "

first_topping = raw_input ('Please give me a topping: ')
if first_topping in topping_list_one :
    print '{}!'.format(success_message + first_topping) 
else : 
    print '{}'.format(error_message + first_topping)
print 'Heres a list of the items now in our inventory: {}'.format(topping_list_one)
```

Both:

```
topping_list_one = ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'cheese', 'peppers']
error_message = "Sorry we don't have "
success_message = "Great, we have "
char = '?=!'

first_topping = raw_input ('Please give me a topping: ')
if first_topping in topping_list_one :
    print '{}!'.format(success_message + first_topping) 
elif first_topping not in topping_list_one and first_topping not in char : 
    topping_list_one.append(first_topping)
else : 
    print '{}'.format(error_message + first_topping)
print 'Heres a list of the items now in our inventory: {}'.format(topping_list_one)
```

PS: Not tested, purely theoretical.